# How to cache items in Project Reactor and avoid a Cache Stampede?

Tags: java-8, project-reactor, caffeine

How can I perform a get/compute lookup that is non blocking and will avoid a cache stampede.

Here is an example that will not stampede, but is blocking.

```
public static <KEY, VALUE> Mono<VALUE> lookupAndWrite(
    Map<KEY, Signal<? extends VALUE>> cacheMap, KEY key, Mono<VALUE> mono) {
    return Mono.defer(() -> Mono.just(cacheMap.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> 
        mono.materialize().block())).dematerialize());
}
```

Here is an example that will not block, but can stampede.

```
public static <KEY, VALUE> MonoCacheBuilderCacheMiss<KEY, VALUE> lookup(
        Function<KEY, Mono<Signal<? extends VALUE>>> reader, KEY key) {
    return otherSupplier -> writer -> Mono.defer(() ->
            reader.apply(key)
                    .switchIfEmpty(otherSupplier.get()
                            .materialize()
                            .flatMap(signal -> writer.apply(key, signal)
                            )
                    )
                    .dematerialize());
}
```

Is there an approach that will not stampede or block?  Would it make sense to just subscribe the blocking call on its own scheduler?

Comment: Would using `AsyncLoadingCache` make sense here? Then you don't block during the computation and the cache adds callbacks for when the future value completes (successfully or by error). (P.S. `AsyncCache` will be in next release, but is easy to emulate)

Comment: @BenManes I am not sure.  The key does not contain enough information to know how to load the data (maybe that doesn't matter).

Comment: You can avoid the `get(key)` call and have the loader throw an exception, to degrade to an ad hoc `AsyncCache`. Then you can write your code in a similar manner as `cache.get(key, k -> mono.toFuture())`

Comment: Since SO isn't great for discussions, we can bring this back to your [github issue](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-addons/issues/162) if you'd like.

Comment: @BenManes If you think that is best.  I brought it up here in hopes of getting some more eyes on it as this seems like it could be a very common problem which has yet to have been raised (for this framework).

Comment: Sure, either is fine. I'll write a small proposal as an answer for you to digest

Comment: @BenManes Cool!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To rephrase your question, you want to avoid stampeding while allowing the computation to be performed asynchronously. This would ideally be done using a `ConcurrentMap<K, Mono<V>>` with `computeIfAbsent` that will discard the entry if the computation fails.

Caffeine's `AsyncLoadingCache` provides this type of behavior by using `CompletableFuture<V>` as the value type. You could rewrite your blocking function as

```
public static <KEY, VALUE> Mono<VALUE> lookupAndWrite(
    AsyncLoadingCache<KEY, VALUE> cache, KEY key, Mono<VALUE> mono) {
  return Mono.defer(() -> Mono.fromFuture(cache.get(key, (k,e) ->
            mono.subscribeOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(e)).toFuture())));
}
```

As of version 2.6.x, there is no simpler `AsyncCache` to hear feedback if desired and it will be in the 2.7 release. This will also include a `ConcurrentMap<K, CompletableFuture<V>>` view which would let you generalize your method to not have a provider-specific interface. For now, you can mimic a non-loading cache by avoiding the loading methods and using `Caffeine.newBuilder().buildAsync(key -> null)`.

Comment: Thank you sir, is there anyway to control if a Mono which is in error is cached.

Comment: No, as a synchronous `ConcurrentMap` wouldn't cache an exception or null value the async cache does the same for the future. If you want to a _negative cache_, then transform to a successful result that you can query, e.g. `Mono<Optional<V>>`. That approach seems to cause the least confusion, keep the interfaces consistent, and not complicate the cache with different handling strategies.